# How to use protobuf's compiled static serialization dll?

Tags: c#, serialization, dll, protobuf-net

So my concern here is when I'm targeting AOT platforms so no support for dynamic code generation. protobuf-net allows to compile the serializers before hand solving the problem. But I'm not quite sure how to use this features...

So I create a `RuntimeTypeModel` with all my types and members and then call `model.Compile(name, path);` - OK... what to do with this generated dll? include it and use its serialize methods and forget about my model object? or can I just serialize from the same model object? (i.e. if I do `model.Compile` if I then say `model.Seiralize`, will the model use the serializers in the compiled dll? or...?)

Any enlightenment on the subject would be great. I found bits and bytes on the Internets but no complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a bit on:

- whether you need cross platform support
- whether you need custom configuration

It sounds like "no" and "yes" in that order, from the question. In which case you *should* be able to use the overload of `Compile` that accepts a path and serializer type name. This emits a DLL that you can reference from your project; do that, and then simply use the serializer type:

```
TypeModel serializer = new YourCustomSerializer();
```

This then had the methods to serialize / deserialize etc.

If you need cross-platform support, the tool to compile is more complicated, and requires using a special build step. The simplest way to do this is via the "protogen" tool, which uses attribute-based configuration. If you need cross-platform compilation *and* custom configuration, you need to write a small tool (not big) that references the *ikvm* protobuf-net; this takes a bit more explaining - let me know if you need an example!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I fall under the first category i.e. I can emit that dll from unity at edit-time and reference it. I do want custom configurations yes, like you've seen from my previous question I had some custom rules for my seralization. I don't think right now I want to support every platform... The main platforms I'd like to have are: PC, Mac, iOS and Android... If creating a dll and referencing it and creating a model from it like you mention first supports all those, then I'm good :D

Comment: However; I still have some doubt... like, you're creating a serializer from `YourCustomSerializer` which is the serializer that's in the dll. But before this step, I have to create a model with some types, and then compile it, right...? so 1- `var model = ResolveTypes(types);` 2- `model.Compile(name, path);` 3- `var serializer = new MyCustomSerializer();` ... and then use that model for serialization, is that it?

Comment: @vexe no. The Compile step needs to be done ahead of time, perhaps as a one-time or on-demand build step. You then ship the generated dll, and instantiate the type from that dll. You can also then switch to "CoreOnly" if you want (and if there is one for ypur platform)

Comment: Well the first step (resolving types) I will also perform in the editor - not runtime... otherwise, how can I compile a model with my custom rules and types?

Comment: So... I'm having some issues. 1- I did a `model.Compile("MySerializer", "path/to/my/serializer");` and I got an error saying that I can't use a full path in my path argument? - I had to change it to `model.Compile("MySerilizer", "MySerializer.dll");` - the doc about that argument didn't mention anything out of the ordinary. Another thing, it seems that I'm only limited to public fields compiling like this? why? is there no workaround?

Comment: @vexe yes, you are limited to public members (properties and fields) - because otherwise it will fail IL validation and Fusion will refuse to load it. You're only allowed to cheat when it isn't looking too hard ;p